# Can I use a 24V, 1A fuse for a 5V application?

Tags: fuses

I have a 5V power supply which needs protection. I only have a 24V, 1A fuse. Can I use this fuse for the 5V power supply.

As Watt = R * I * I = V * I.
As rated W is constant for a given fuse, will the current at which the fuse blows increase if Voltage decreases?

Comment: A fuse is not a resistor so ohms law does not apply to it. _"As rated W is constant for a given fuse"_ No such thing!

Comment: @winny What makes you think a fuse isn't a resistor?  W = I²R.  If W exceeds a certain value, the fuse wire overheats and melts.

Comment: @SimonB Not in the way OP thinks of it. But sure, it's a resistor alright.

Comment: @Simon B no, if current exceeds the rating, the fuse opens.  Power has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @RDrast So it doesn't matter even if the fuse is rated for 240Vac?

Comment: @PraneshRao Know that DC gives fuses a harder time than AC since AC will periodically cross zero to self-extinguish the arc when fuse blows. So a 240VDC fuse is fine in place of a 240VAC fuse, but not the other way around. But 240VAC is so much higher than 5VDC that the 240VAC would work just fine in that situation Same goes for relays.

Answer (score 9):

The 24 V printed on the fuse is only relevant **after the fuse has blown**. There is no need to calculate the power (\$P=I^2R\$).

*Why is that so?*

When the fuse is intact, it will have a low resistance so the dissipated power will be low.

When the fuse has blow, no current should flow so then the power is **zero**.

So the case where both current and voltage are high (like 1 A, 24 V) should never happen.

After the fuse has blown, it must be able to keep the circuit open (not connected). The fuse can do this up to a certain voltage. For a 1A / 24 v fuse, that voltage is 24 V.

So as long as there is no more than 24 V across the fuse when it is blown, there is no issue. Your 5 V application has a low enough voltage so this fuse is suitable.

You would **not** want to use a 1 A / 24 V fuse in a mains voltage ( 120 V or 240 V AC) as then the voltage is too high and the fuse might not be able to keep the circuit open after it has blown.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
So does that mean that I can use even a fuse rated for 230Vac/1A for the 5Vdc/1A application?

Comment: @PraneshRao Yes, in the same way you can reinforced steel bunker door to keep a cat out of the house.

Comment: There’s more to applying fuses than just the amperage rating. Google “fuse curves” and you will see. You need the fuse to blow before the equipment it is protecting is damaged. There are many different fuse characteristics (slow, fast etc.).